# Should pending intents be canceled if they are not used

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an App which can create multiple notifications in the status bar with NotificationManager. Each notification has a PendingIntent instance (with a unique request code) for opening an activity when its clicked. The user can also cancel the notification which means that the pending intent will never be used.

Should I manually clear each PendingIntent to prevent memory leak or the system can handle this by itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah! It's better to clear each and every unused PendingIndent programatically so that your application performance will be better.